# Setting a sh file to git bash

Tags: windows, bash, git

I've created a Python "automation" task that will initialize a repository on github and then on my bash function I'll be creating a folder, initialize the repository as the code bellow shows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

function repo() {
    cd
    python C:/Users/wsm/PycharmProjects/GitAutomation/create.py $1
    cd C:/Users/wsm/$1
    start .
    git init
    git remote add origin <mygithublink>/$1.git
    touch README.md
    git add .
    git commit -m "Initial commit"
    git push -u origin master
    code .
}
```

The only problem is that I have to use source command everytime I close a git bash to enable the command `repo` (Name of the function) again. Any ideas on how to make that command permanent on Windows 10?

Comment: Source the function from your shell's interactive startup files. But really, if this is a separate script, why make it a function at all? Just take out the function definition and save it as an executable script in your `PATH`.

Comment: Also, [quote your variables.](/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)

Comment: So, what I should do is turn it into a .exe and add to the system variable path?

Comment: The script itself is executable, there is no need (and no way really) to turn it into an .exe.

Comment: I see, it worked just fine. Appreciate it